# Aspnet Entity Data Model wont work as expected

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-identity, sql-server-express

To start with I'm really new into developing with C#, ASPNET, and MS SQL so perhaps I'm just missing a simple point here or missunterstood a basic concept so please have patience with me :)

I'm Using Visual Studio Web Deveoloper 2010 Express with .NET Framework 4 and MVC2 (Have to use this specific Version). I also have SQL Management Studio 10.5 where I created a simple Table [image]

Now I want to use this as an entity model so I created one in Visual Studio and added all Tables (including the ASPNET User Tables) and Stored Procedures.[image]

The Problem is the Result...

[image]

I expected to be able to navigate from Kunden(createdBy, modifiedBy) to the ASPNET User Table like i can access "Geschenk" from the "Kunden" Table. I thought I will have a single Property here and not 2 of them for the same reason. Of course I could just rename the Navigation Properties but I want to know whats the cause of this and whats the proper way to use aspnetusers in this case?

Comment: Your expectation is wrong. EF builds a unique navigation property for each foreign key reference. One of those properties is the mapping for the user record that created the Kunden record, and the other is the mapping for the user record of the last user that modified it.

Comment: I would also strongly recommend updating to the [Community edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx), as what you're using isn't supported at this point.

Comment: @TiesonT. So the Navigation property is not created for the same object its in the sql table but for the object it "links to" ?

Comment: Or is this just for m:n relations? Then how is the Name of the Property determited or why isnt createdBy and modifiedBy is used as Navigation Property?

Comment: Yes to the first, and I'm not sure what you mean by the second. The navigation property is named for the table/set that it links to, more or less. Probably should read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx)

Comment: ok so because the destination is "Aspnet_User" they got named "...Users1" and "..."Users2" ?

Comment: When more than one foreign key exists from one table to another table, you would get duplicate navigation properties. To avoid that, EF appends a number after every duplicate after the first. Which one is "first" varies with the order in which the columns appear in the schema, if I remember correctly.

Comment: Thank you, now I got it - After reading the document you linked it seems to me that I got multiple things the wrong way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Kunden` has 2 FK references to the `aspnet_Users` table.  One corresponds to the `createdBy` column and the other corresponds to the `modifiedBy` column.  Consequently, a navigation property is generated for each.  Imagine that different users had created and modified a single `Kunden`.

If only a single association were generated, which user would you expect the `aspnet_Users` association to retrieve?  If you're expecting a collection of both, then how would you distinguish between the two?